# Can you edit your description of your flag submission after it's actually submitted?

Tags: support, flags

For the first time I've used flagging feature.
I am specifically focusing on:

**'Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)'**
*This question needs a moderator's attention. Please describe exactly what's wrong.*

I have submitted my reason and it was successfully submitted for the moderators to look at it.
However, some of my spellings were incorrect and the sentence is unclear.
I was wondering.. Is there any way I can edit my submitted flag description and resubmit it or not.

**Edit**
It's fairly straightforward to understand that you can resubmit it.
But what will happen if that question was removed by the author and your unclear description (that needs to be fixed as it is crucial) is still pending?
I know SO and MSO demands clear description, question and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to edit your flag text once it is submitted.  If you left out something *really vital* you could submit a second flag.  This certainly wouldn't be appropriate for just minor spelling changes though.